# Non-Linear Optimization Methods for scalar function of a Matrix

Tags: matrix-equations, nonlinear-optimization, matrix-calculus, hessian-matrix

I need some advice as to how to update a matrix of triplets in a likelihood function.

**DEFINITIONS**

$ \beta =$ scalar scaling parameter

$ \alpha = $ scalar shape parameter

$ X = $ Nx3 matrix of triples, each a point in 3D space ( so the $i^{th}$ row of X is $ x_i , y_i , z_i $ )

$ d_{ij} = $ distance between $ (x_i , y_i , z_i) $ and $ (x_j , y_j , z_j) $, $j \ge i$

$r_{ij} =  (1 \times N)$ vector with $i^{th}$ entry equal to 1, $j^{th}$ entry equal to -1, and 0 everywhere else. $j \ge i$

$c_{ij} =$ constants, $j \ge i$

**AIM**

My aim is to maximize the following function with respect to {$\alpha, \beta, X$}:

$$ L(d,\alpha,\beta | c) = \alpha \sum_{ij} c_{ij} \log{d_{ij}} + \log{\beta}\sum_{ij} c_{ij} - \beta \sum_{ij} d_{ij}^{\alpha} $$

**A BIT OF ALGEBRA**

Using the equation $ d_{ij} = \sqrt{ (x_i - x_j)^2 + ( y_i - y_j )^2 + (z_i - z_j)^2 } $, I can rewrite the equation in terms of the X matrix.

There are $n(n-1)/2$ observations ($c_{ij}$s) and $n(n-1)/2 + 2$ parameters ($d_{ij}$'s,$\alpha,\beta$).  So converting to triplets reduces the dimension of the parameter space (as n is usually in the hundreds of thousands, if not millions) to $3n+2$.

$d_{ij}^2 = (x_i - x_j)^2 + ( y_i - y_j )^2 + (z_i - z_j)^2 = Tr(X^{'}r_{ij}r_{ij}^{'}X) = Tr(r_{ij}^{'}XX^{'}r_{ij}) = r_{ij}^{'}XX^{'}r_{ij} $

So, my equation becomes

$$ L(X,\alpha,\beta | c) = \frac{\alpha}{2} \sum_{ij} c_{ij} \log{(r_{ij}^{'}XX^{'}r_{ij})} + \log{\beta}\sum_{ij} c_{ij} - \beta \sum_{ij} (r_{ij}^{'}XX^{'}r_{ij})^{\frac{\alpha}{2}} $$

**HOW I'VE APPROACHED IT**

I know that that are an infinite number of possible translated and rotated X's, but we can add constraints to X, such as

- $x_1>0$, $y_1=z_1=0$ (i.e. the first point is always on the positive x-axis)
- $y_2 > 0$, $z_2=0$ (second point is on the x,y plane, and cross prod of first and second point is positive)
- $\sum x_i = \sum y_i = \sum z_i = 0$
- $d_{ij} \le |j-i|$  $\forall i<j$

These constraints also increase our degrees to estimate the parameters.

I thought of iteratively cycling through {$\beta,\alpha,X$} and maximizing w.r.t each.

Taking the derivative w.r.t. $\beta$ and setting to zero gives

$$ \beta^{(t+1)} = \frac{\sum_{ij}c_{ij}}{\sum_{ij}(r_{ij}^{'}XX^{'}r_{ij})^{ \alpha^{(t)}/2} } $$

Taking the derivative w.r.t. $\alpha$ gives:

$$ \sum_{ij} c_{ij}\log{(r_{ij}^{'}XX^{'}r_{ij})} - \frac{\beta}{2} \sum_{ij} (r_{ij}^{'}XX^{'}r_{ij})^{\alpha/2}\log{(r_{ij}^{'}XX^{'}r_{ij})} $$

I could either set this to zero and find a solution for $\alpha$ numerically, or use this expression in a Newton-Raphson update for $\alpha$.

$$\alpha^{(t+1)} = \alpha^{(t)} + \frac{ L(\alpha^{(t)}) }{ L'(\alpha^{(t)}) }$$

**WHERE I HIT A DEAD END**

I would next like to find an iterative update to *the entire X matrix* and then repeat the above process.

Using Matrix differentiation $\frac{d}{dX'}a'XX'b = X'(ab'+ba')$ ==> $\frac{d}{dX'}r'XX'r = 2X'rr$' (feel free to check my work) I get:

$$\frac{d}{dX'}L(X,\alpha,\beta | c) = \alpha \sum_{ij} \frac{ c_{ij} }{ r_{ij}^{'}XX^{'}r_{ij} } (X^{'}r_{ij}r_{ij}^{'}) - \alpha\beta \sum_{ij} (r_{ij}^{'}XX'r_{ij})^{ \frac{\alpha-2}{2} }(X^{'}r_{ij}r_{ij}^{'})$$

$$=\alpha X' \left[\sum_{ij} \frac{ r_{ij}r_{ij}^{'} }{ r_{ij}^{'}XX^{'}r_{ij} } \left[c_{ij} - \beta (r_{ij}^{'}XX'r_{ij})^{ \frac{\alpha}{2} }\right] \right]$$

The above expression is a $3 \times N$ matrix.

- This is non-linear, so I cannot set to zero solve for X directly.
- I cannot use Newton-Raphson to update $X^{(t+1)}$ because I cannot divide $L(X,\alpha,\beta | c)$ by $L'(X,\alpha,\beta | c)$
- I'm not sure how else I would solve it numerically.

My colleagues have suggested "interior point methods" my be useful.  If you would, please explain to me how interior point methods would work in this context, or please suggest some other reasonable approach.

Thanks!

Comment: With multivariate optimization, the Newton-Raphson method asks us to invert a matrix, rather than "divide... by $L'(X,\alpha,\beta\mid c)$".  That said, you probably want to use some more robust algorithm to get close to the optimum before trying Newton-Raphson iterations.

Comment: Yes, that is a fair point.  I should mention that I already have done "Nonmetric Multi-dimensional Scaling" (NMDS) to obtain reasonable starting positions for X.   

To your point about inverting a matrix, my derivative w.r.t. X is a 3xn matrix, so I cannot invert it for a NR type update.

Comment: As I count it, you have eleven parameters: the nine entries of $X$ and the two values $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  Since you are maximizing $L$, the Newton-Raphson method is looking for simultaneous vanishing of the first partials of $L$ wrt the eleven parameters.  It's the $11\times 11$ Hessian matrix of second partial derivatives that needs inverting.

Comment: @hardmath Thank you very much for the feedback!  However, there are many thousands of entries in the x matrix, as it is 3xN, so not just 9 entries.  There are constraints on the first two rows, but every row after that is unconstrained (except that the three columns of length N sum to zero, which is easily achieved by subtracting the average value for each column).

Comment: Still, the matrix to be inverted for N-R is a square matrix (of second partial derivatives).  When there are a large number of parameters (many thousands in your case), we typically work with updates based on implicit approximations to the inverse (rather than try to update and invert the Hessian at each step).  I have a better idea now of some optimization methods that may be of interest, and I'll try to organize an outline for you.